# Windows 10 update stuck at starting download

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-upgrade

I'm trying to update to Windows 10 from Windows 7 Home Premium 64-Bit.
The GWX updater has been stuck at the "Starting download ..." screen for an hour or so.

I have restarted the download and the GWX.exe a few times. I also tried updating via the Windows Update.

I've checked the network usage via Task Manager and it just does nothing.
This is a screenshot from starting the GWX.exe and then waiting a while: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uf70.jpg.
Maybe anyone here can help?

Comment: Alternatively you can use the Microsoft Media Creation tool to Install W10, run it and choose the Install Now option....https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: @Moab comment provides good details on what I called option 3. Its the highest effort but most likely to succeed option.

Comment: They might need the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following these steps are the most commonly successful fix to that issue:

1. Open an admin command prompt
2. Type `net stop wuauserv`
3. Type `net stop bits`
4. Delete this directory: `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution`
5. Reboot. If you were unable to delete the directory in step 4 boot into safe mode and finish deletion there.
6. Boot into Windows and restart update.

If this does not work there are other methods to try that I can detail if needed. In summary these are:

1. Windows update troubleshooter ( occasionally works)
2. Run `sfc /scannow` as admin. Resolve identified issues if any, redo steps at top
3. Admit defeat, just download the ISO installer and manually kick off the update.
4. Admit defeat, format drive and install the exciting new Fedora 24 beta!

Comment: from the secondary methods the 3rd one worked. rest didn't work. Thank you!

Comment: Moab deserves any credit. Glad it worked out. 4 was a joke that probably got 2 laughs (me twice) but I was kind of hoping you'd go down that road.